# Martingales associated with heat equation

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, martingales, heat-equation

I am trying to learn the connection between Brownian motion and heat equation (in the spirit of Feynman-Kac, for example, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306978/full-proof-references-for-markov-generators-with-various-boundary-conditions)). I read (Michael E. Taylor's PDE book, Volume II, Chapter 11, Proposition 4.5) that the solution $h(t, x)$ of the backward heat equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ gives rise to a martingale, in the sense that $h(t, \omega(t))$ is a martingale, where $\omega(t)$ is a Brownian path starting at $x$.

It seems quite natural to consider this question on bounded domains. Now, consider a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary. Suppose $h^D(t, x)$ and $h^N(t, x)$ solve the backward heat equation on $\Omega$ with Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions respectively. Also (via Feynman-Kac), these heat flows correspond to Brownian paths $\omega^D(t)$ and $\omega^N(t)$ which are stopped upon impact at boundary and reflected from boundary respectively.

Now, my question is: are the processes $h^D(t, \omega^D(t))$ and $h^N(t, \omega^N(t))$ martingales?

I suspect the answer is yes, as the proof in Taylor's book seems to depend only on the semigroup property of $e^{t\Delta}$ and the Markovian nature of the Brownian motion, both of which should be true in the above situation also. Am I missing something? Any help will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Yes: as long as you can write $h(t,x)$ as the expectation of the underlying Markov process $X_t$: $h(t,x) = \mathbb E^x h(T,X_{T-t})$, then $h(t,X_t)$ is a $\mathbb P^x$-martingale. This is straightforward to verify using one of the many formulations of the Markov property: $h(t,X_t) = \mathbb E^{X_t}(h(T,X_T)) = \mathbb E^x(h(T,X_T) | \mathscr F_t)$ a.s. under $\mathbb P^x$, where $\mathscr F_t$ is the natural filtration.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thanks for your reply. In this relation, I am having a small confusion about the application of the optional stopping theorem. Suppose the solution $h(t, x)$ to the backward heat equation is given by $e^{t\lambda}u(x)$, where $u$ is a higher eigenfunction of the Laplacian with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Since $u$ is sign changing, you start from a point where $h(t, x) < 0$ and stop the motion at a positive level set of $h$. To me this seems to contradict the optional stopping theorem by giving negative = positive. What am I missing?

Comment: In my comment I meant $T$ is a finite deterministic time. However, of course you can define $h(t,x)=e^{\lambda t}u(x)$ for all $t > 0$, and then consider the stopping time $\tau = \inf\{t \geqslant 0:u(X_t)>0$. What you might be missing here is the fact that $u(t\wedge\tau,X_{t\wedge\tau}$ is not uniformly integrable, so there is no reason to expect that $u(0,x)=\mathbb E^xu(\tau,X_\tau)$. Just as stopping the Wiener process when it first hits $1$ does not prove that $0 = 1$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I think I see my misconception now. By the way, I saw that Exercises 3.11 and 3.12 of Richard F. Bass' book  "Stochastic Processes" addresses exactly this situation.

Comment: $h^D(t, \omega^D(t))$ is a martingale, but for  $h^N(t, \omega^N(t))$ you need an additional compensating term $\int_0^t D_nh(s,\omega^N(s)) dL_s$, where $D_n$ indicates inward pointing normal derivative on the boundary of $\Omega$, and $L$ is suitably normalized local time on $\delta \Omega$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I have now done some reading on this, and it seems to me that whether $h^N(t, \omega^N(t))$ is a martingale or not depends on the precise function space on which the question is being posed. For example, if all my functions have normal derivative zero at the boundary, then the process should become a martingale. Is my understanding correct? Thanks!